# How do you return stolen packets back to Netfilter

Tags: linux, netfilter

Let's say I have intercepted a packet from Netfilter and subsequently returned NF_STOLEN.  At some point I want to re-inject that packet back to, in this case, the TCP stream it came from.  I want to do this from Kernel space.  So far I have been unable to find a way to do this.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, should have searched a bit longer...

nf_reinject(..) seems to be proper way of handling this.

Comment: How embarrassing. Seems nf_reinject only works if NF_QUEUE was returned.  So, still looking for an amswer if the packet was stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain what really you want to achieve here. Because if you return `NF_STOLEN`, that means you have already sent/processed that packet (i.e by calling `dev_queue_xmit`). If you have not sent or consumed that packet and want to be processed by kernel later then use `NF_QUEUE` and `nf_reinject`.